# Floating Point operators correctly rounded implementation

Tags: floating-point, precision

I'm Implementing a floating point library in C, basically it's based on the IEEE standard. I've started with the addition.

I've some problem to understand the rounding.

Maybe an example could help

```
x = -3.652248e-11 
y = 1.263346e-10 
Cz = 8.981213e-11
Mz = 8.981214e-11
Cz = 8.98121e-11
Mz = 8.98121e-11
x = ae20a0a7
y = 2f0ae808
Cf = 2ec57fbc
Mf = 2ec57fbd
Cz = 457fbc
Mz = 457fbd
Ce = 5d
Me = 5d
```

In the above, `x` and `y` are random input value, `Cz` is the result of the C operator `+` and finally `Mz` is the result of my implementation.

`Cf` and `Mf` are bit representation of the final result. As you can see the final bit is different and i don't understand why. I've took inspiration for my implementation from an handbook of floating point arithmetic.

What I do not understand, I guess, is how actually the rounding is performed. My addition algorithm is based on the identity

```
x + y = (-1)^{sx}2^Ex(|x| + (-1)^(sx xor sy) |y| 2^{Ey-Ex})
```

where if I name the quantity

```
|z| = (|x| + (-1)^(sx xor sy) |y| 2^{Ey-Ex})
```

Basically the problem arises when I need to post-normalize the result using left shifting, be careful in my case `|z|` is always positive. Which rounding technique should be applied here in this case?

Comment: It's hard to definitively tell you exactly what's going wrong here, because you haven't printed enough digits of `x` and `y` to uniquely identify their values.  Can you add their bit representations to the question, please?  My best guess is that your implementation simply doesn't have a guard digit, but it's hard to be sure without that information.

Comment: Techinically the implementation is the one suggested in this book https://books.google.it/books?id=baFvrIOPvncC&pg=PA338&dq=handbook+of+floating+point+arithmetic+software+implementation+addition&hl=en&sa=X&ei=8IlMVc6EMLGd7gb-4IKwCg&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=handbook%20of%20floating%20point%20arithmetic%20software%20implementation%20addition&f=false section 10.2, floating point addition where there's code snippet for some case. In summary that implementation should be for correctly rounded function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My copy of Muller et al. is on loan to a friend, so I can't double-check the algorithm that you're using specifically, but walking through addition of the values you list:

```
x = 0xae20a0a7 = -b1.01000001010000010100111 * 2^-35
y = 0x2f0ae808 = +b1.00010101110100000001000 * 2^-33
```

If we normalize `x` and `y` to a common exponent and add, we get the un-normalized infinitely precise result:

```
  b100.01010111010000000100000 * 2^-35
-   b1.01000001010000010100111 * 2^-35
-------------------------------------
   b11.00010101111111101111001 * 2^-35
```

Now normalize without rounding yet:

```
b1.10001010111111110111100 1 * 2^-34
                          ^
                          rounding point
```

The infinitely-precise result is exactly halfway between the two nearest floating-point numbers, so we choose the *even* one, and round down to

```
b1.10001010111111110111100 * 2^-34 = 0x2ec57fbc
```

Given that this is an exact halfway case, the most likely explanation for why you're not getting the correct answer is that you're not handling this *ties to even* part of the rounding rule correctly.  If you try to round by simply adding half an ulp and truncating, you would get exactly the result you are observing.